# Edit XML namespace element

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, xsd-validation

I am trying to validate an XML file using an XSD schema but according to the documentation the namespace for the XML file needs to have something added to the namespace. Is there a function to do this using XDocument or something or must I just use brute force?

Comment: You can update the namespace using XNamespace. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnamespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: How would I take the existing namespace, change it, then put it back, using that?

Comment: You've tagged this question with both `c#` and `vb.net`. Which one are you using?